# Failed loading configuration file for discord bots

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm attempting to make a `server.js` file to load both of my discord bots on the same PloxHost server. But it keeps failing at the `tokens.json` file.

Here is my `tokens.json` file:

```json
{
    token1 = TOKEN,
    token2 = TOKEN
}
```

Here is the error it keeps throwing:

```js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1109
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /home/container/config/tokens.json: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 6
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1106:22)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/server.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
```

and here is my `server.js` file:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client1 = new Discord.Client();
const client2 = new Discord.Client();
const CONFIG = require('./config/tokens.json');

client1.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot 1 ready.');
});

client2.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot 2 ready.');
});

client1.login(CONFIG.token1);
client2.login(CONFIG.token2);
```

Both bots are running discord.js v12. Is there something that has changed about json file formats?

I've tried using these formats as well but still no go:

```json
{
    token1 = TOKEN
};{
    token2 =TOKEN
}
```

```json
{
    "token1" = "TOKEN",
    "token2" = "TOKEN"
}
```

```json
{
    "token1" = "TOKEN";
    "token2" = "TOKEN"
}
```

I'm at a stand still here. I've honestly never had this much trouble with json formatting and I'm really needing to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is structured as `"key": value`, where  `value` can be anything from a string, boolean, number, to an object of some kind (including arrays). These are comma-delimited.

You can check whether your JSON is valid via [a JSON linter](https://jsonlint.com/).

The correct syntax for this would be:

**tokens.json**

```json
{
  "token1": "TOKEN",
  "token2": "TOKEN"
}
```

For sensitive values such as tokens, I would look into storing these in your environment. You can put these into a file called `.env` or configure them as environmental variables. These will be available under [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env) at run-time.

I'd look at the [`dotenv`](https://npmjs.com/dotenv) package for this.

**.env** (root of project -- do not commit)

```
token1=TOKEN
token2=TOKEN
```

**server.js**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client1 = new Discord.Client();
const client2 = new Discord.Client();
require('dotenv').config();

client1.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot 1 ready.');
});

client2.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot 2 ready.');
});

client1.login(process.env.token1);
client2.login(process.env.token2);
```

Comment: ty. this was annoying me soo much. and yeas the dotenv thing is actually really smart. i shouldve realized i could do that with the main file =)

Comment: For sure. It's good practice to do this for sensitive operations, but also moving parts that would otherwise require a code change. I'd often consolidate these into a single config file that I set as `main` in my package.json (i.e. for [three.js](https://github.com/threejs/discord-bot/blob/main/src/config.js)).